# Display calendar in added row

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have a table that displays new row each time we click on ADD NEW. The first row has calendar image next to input field that show calendar box each time we click on the calendar image. The issue is :after we click on ADD NEW ROW the calendar image is shown but **when we click on it the calendar box is not displayed**. 
How can i display calendar box of the row that show after we click on ADD NEW ?

```
 $(function() {
        $("#datearrive").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
               buttonImageOnly: true,
               buttonText: "Select date"

        }).val()

  $("#datearrive").click(function() {

            date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
            $( "#datearrive" ).datepicker( "setDate" , date);

    }); 

});
 $(function() {
        $("#datedepart").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
               buttonImageOnly: true,
               buttonText: "Select date"

        }).val()

  $("#datedepart").click(function() {

            date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
            $( "#datedepart" ).datepicker( "setDate" , date);

    }); 

});
 <table id="maintable">
        <tr>
            <th align="center">Arrived Date</th>
            <th align="center">Departed Date</th>
            <th align="center">Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rows">
            <div style="padding-left: 5px">
                <td style="padding:5px;">
                    <input type="text" name="rollno" id="datearrive" />
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="datedepart" />
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px;">
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" />
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <br>
        <div id="add_new">ADD NEW</div>
 $("#add_new").click(function () { 

$("#maintable").each(function () {

    var tds = '<tr>';
    jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
        tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
    });
    tds += '</tr>';
    if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
        $('tbody', this).append(tds);
    } else {
        $(this).append(tds);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points before the answer :-

1. Your generated rows will have same IDs and I am pretty sure you know that Id has to be unique , so first change it to class;
2. For dynamically generated elements you have to bind them for any function to work on them . Use jquery method "on" for this call.
3. I have wrote the following code with on and changed the id to classes , the calender will show but all the values will be same for corresponding arrival and departure dates , to overcome this I would suggest generating IDs anyway here the code with classes and "on" method.

> ```
>  <script>
>  $(function() {
>        $('body').on('focus',"input.datearrive", function(){
>           $(".datearrive").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
>                 showOn: "button",
>                 buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
>                buttonImageOnly: true,
>                buttonText: "Select date"
>
>         }).val()
>       });
>
>
>   $("body").on('click','input.datearrive',function() {
>
>             date = new Date();
>             date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
>             $( ".datearrive" ).datepicker( "setDate" , date);
>
>     }); 
>
> });
>  $(function() {
>       $('body').on('focus',"input.datedepart", function(){
>           $(".datedepart").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
>                   showOn: "button",
>                   buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
>                  buttonImageOnly: true,
>                  buttonText: "Select date"
>
>           }).val()
>       });
>
>   $("body").on('click','input.datedepart',function() {
>
>             date = new Date();
>             date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
>             $( ".datedepart" ).datepicker( "setDate" , date);
>
>     }); 
>
> });
> </script>
>  <table id="maintable">
>         <tr>
>             <th align="center">Arrived Date</th>
>             <th align="center">Departed Date</th>
>             <th align="center">Last Name</th>
>         </tr>
>         <tr id="rows">
>             <div style="padding-left: 5px">
>                 <td style="padding:5px;">
>                     <input type="text" name="rollno" class="datearrive" />
>                 </td>
>                 <td style="padding:5px;">
>                     <input type="text" name="firstname" class="datedepart" />
>                 </td>
>                 <td style="padding:5px;">
>                     <input type="text" name="lastname" />
>                 </td>
>             </div>
>         </tr>
>     </table>
>         <br>
>         <div id="add_new">ADD NEW</div>
>       <script>
>  $("#add_new").click(function () { 
>
> $("#maintable").each(function () {
>
>     var tds = '<tr>';
>     jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
>         tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
>     });
>     tds += '</tr>';
>     if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
>         $('tbody', this).append(tds);
>     } else {
>         $(this).append(tds);
>     }
> });
> });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: with yours changes ADD NEW ROW work but   first row and rows after click are not showing calendars..

Comment: i fix every thing i just closed the parenthesis and braket it works. Thanks